# The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before loadAd is called. App is breaking

Tags: android, eclipse, navigation-drawer, ads, interstitial

I've publish my application. After updating eclipse it don't function, why?
this is my logcat:`01-18 21:48:02.508: E/AndroidRuntime(494): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-18 21:48:02.508: E/AndroidRuntime(494): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.beandroid.androchef/com.beandroid.csipordenone.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before loadAd is called.
01-18 21:48:02.508: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-18 21:48:02.508: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-18 21:48:02.508: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-18 21:48:02.508: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-18 21:48:02.508: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-18 21:48:02.508: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-18 21:48:02.508: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-18 21:48:02.508: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-18 21:48:02.508: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-18 21:48:02.508: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-18 21:48:02.508: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-18 21:48:02.508: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-18 21:48:02.508: E/AndroidRuntime(494): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before loadAd is called.
01-18 21:48:02.508: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.bh.bn(Unknown Source)
01-18 21:48:02.508: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.bh.a(Unknown Source)
01-18 21:48:02.508: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(Unknown Source)
01-18 21:48:02.508: E/AndroidRuntime(494):  at com.beandroid.csipordenone.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:102)`
This is my Main.java: `enter code here`

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to set :

```
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id"
```

in your AdView.